# To prove the limit of given function does not exist.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions

Ques: I want to show that a limit of a function $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x-y}$$ does not exist at point $(0,0)$.

My try: I am just taking path $y=x-x^{3}$ then $$\lim _{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x-y}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^{3}+(x-x^{3})^{3}}{x^{3}}=2$$
Then i am taking path $y=2(x-x^{3})$ and i got limit $0$. So, in the both case the limit does not remain same. it means limit of given function does not exist.

Am i right? please give your valuable suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to work so hard.  For the limit to exist at a point, the function has to be defined in a punctured neighborhood of this point.  But your function is undefined whenever $x=y$.  Hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: This depends on your definition of a limit. You can find in "little Rudin" that the definition for a limit requires points in the domain within $\delta$ to imply $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Comment: I think the neighborhood has to be a subset of the domain. In this case, the domain doesn't include the set $y=x$. For example, $(x-y)/(x-y)$ clearly exists at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @nayrb: Rudin is referring to a situation where a domain other than an open neighborhood is explicitly specified.

Comment: @Clayton: your claim is incorrect.  The expression $(x-y)/(x-y)$ is undefined when $x=y$.

Comment: @user72694: It is defined for all $x\neq y$. Take that as the domain, and we can view the domain as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$, hence we can talk about limits.

Comment: @Clayton: this condition was not part of the original problem.

Comment: It is standard practice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right, but I get limit 2 for the first one, not 1. For the second limit, I get 9/2, not zero. As @Clayton points out, $y = 0$ will suffice, and as @user72694 points out, there is a much easier way.

Answer (score 1):

That is perfectly right.
You could also say that in every square of edge l around the (0,0) the function assume all real value, so it clearly can not have a unique limit.

Comment: How do you know it assumes all real values? It may, or it may not. You do know it assumes two different values.

Comment: Using  polar coordinates.
(x,y) = (r*cos(t), r*sin(t))
if we leave r fixed and send t to pi / 4 from above it will go to - inf and if we send t to pi*5/4 from below then it will go to +inf and if we restrict the function to x-y < 0 it will be continuos; thus intermediate value Theorem applies