# How to show that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y}$ does not exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

First I tried evaluating the limit along different paths like $y=kx,\:kx^2,\:\sin(x),\:\tan(x)$, etc. and a lot more functions that pass through the origin. However, every single try gives me a value $0$ for the limit.

Then I tried to do it by converting to polar co-ordinates by substituting $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$. But this too gives me a value $0$ for the limit.

The question is to show it doesn't exist, but I keep getting the same value from every path and method. Am I missing something, or does the limit actually exist?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/460289/42969 – both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7B(x%2Cy)%5Cto(0%2C0)%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E3%2By%5E3%7D%7Bx-y%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Thank you so much!